# How can I update the value of my selection

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a piano website that makes random melodies based on their scales. But when I choose a certain key and/or scale and/or mode(different kind of scale), the dropdown doesn't update in JS.

JS Code:

```
const specifiedNote = document.querySelector('#keys').value;
const majorMinor = document.querySelector('#types').value;
const mode = document.querySelector('#modes').value;


//Checking to see if it changes ever 4 seconds after I select a different value in the drop box
setInterval(()=>{
    console.log(specifiedNote, majorMinor, mode);
}, 4000);
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="keys">
    <select name="keys" id="keys">
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="C#">C#</option>
        <option value="D">D</option>
        <option value="D#">D#</option>
        <option value="E">E</option>
        <option value="F">F</option>
        <option value="F#">F#</option>
        <option value="G">G</option>
        <option value="G#">G#</option>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="A#">A#</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
    </select>
    <select name="types" id="types">
        <option value="Major">Major</option>
        <option value="Minor">Minor</option>
    </select>
    <select name="modes" id="modes">
        <option value="None">None</option>
        <option value="Dorian">Dorian</option>
        <option value="Phrygian">Phrygian</option>
        <option value="Lydian">Lydian</option>
        <option value="Mixolydian">Mixolydian</option>
        <option value="Aeolian">Aeolian</option>
        <option value="Locrian">Locrian</option>
    </select>
    <select name="amount" id="amount">
        <option value="4">4 Notes</option>
        <option value="8">8 Notes</option>
        <option value="16">16 Notes</option>
    </select>
    <button class="create">RELODY!</button>
</div>
```

[image: If you look at the console, you'll see the value is the same over 10 times, but the values in the drop downs are different. How do I fix this?]

If you look at the console, you'll see the value is the same over 10
times, but the values in the drop downs are different. How do I fix this?

Comment: You are taking the value before setTimeout hance inside the timeout the value will be same.

Answer (score 1):

You must read the element again in the the interval function :

```
setInterval(()=>{
    specifiedNote = document.querySelector('#keys').value;
    majorMinor = document.querySelector('#types').value;
    mode = document.querySelector('#modes').value;
    console.log(specifiedNote, majorMinor, mode);
}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must be reading the value inside the `timeout`.

Or another method you can do is, make a change event handler for the selects instead of the `setTimeout`, so the functions work when the select boxes are changed, not periodically.

```js
//Checking to see if it changes ever 4 seconds after I select a different value in the drop box
setInterval(()=>{
  const specifiedNote = document.querySelector('#keys').value;
  const majorMinor = document.querySelector('#types').value;
  const mode = document.querySelector('#modes').value;
  console.log(specifiedNote, majorMinor, mode);
}, 4000);
```

```html
<div class="keys">
    <select name="keys" id="keys">
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="C#">C#</option>
        <option value="D">D</option>
        <option value="D#">D#</option>
        <option value="E">E</option>
        <option value="F">F</option>
        <option value="F#">F#</option>
        <option value="G">G</option>
        <option value="G#">G#</option>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="A#">A#</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
    </select>
    <select name="types" id="types">
        <option value="Major">Major</option>
        <option value="Minor">Minor</option>
    </select>
    <select name="modes" id="modes">
        <option value="None">None</option>
        <option value="Dorian">Dorian</option>
        <option value="Phrygian">Phrygian</option>
        <option value="Lydian">Lydian</option>
        <option value="Mixolydian">Mixolydian</option>
        <option value="Aeolian">Aeolian</option>
        <option value="Locrian">Locrian</option>
    </select>
    <select name="amount" id="amount">
        <option value="4">4 Notes</option>
        <option value="8">8 Notes</option>
        <option value="16">16 Notes</option>
    </select>
    <button class="create">RELODY!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get Values Inside your set interval code like below.

```
setInterval(()=>{
    let specifiedNote = document.querySelector('#keys').value;
    let majorMinor = document.querySelector('#types').value;
    let mode = document.querySelector('#modes').value;
    console.log(specifiedNote, majorMinor, mode);
},
```